# intel_pt data cannot be imported properly into Intel VTune 2018

Tags: intel, trace, perf, intel-vtune

I am using Intel VTune 2018 to profile and derive the control flow dependencies by making use of the Intel_PT PMU under the system:

Kernel: 4.15.0-13-generic, 64bit Ubuntu

CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-7820X @ 3.60GHz × 16

I started with the following commands:

1- amplxe-perf record -o a.perf -T -e intel_pt// -- ps

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
21471 pts/1    00:00:00 amplxe-perf
21472 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
58693 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo
58694 pts/1    00:00:00 su
58695 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
[ perf record: Woken up 2 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 3.154 MB a.perf ]
```

2- amplxe-cl -import a.perf -r folder

```
amplxe: Importing a new result 100 % done                                      
amplxe: Using result path `/home/amad/May2/folder'
amplxe: Executing actions 12 % Loading 'a.perf' file                           
amplxe: Error: Cannot load data file `/home/amad/May2/folder/data.0/a.perf' (Data file is corrupted).
amplxe: Executing actions 50 % done                                            
amplxe: Error: 0x4000001e (Cannot load raw collector data)
```

Although intel_pt data has not been successfully imported, the data for other kernel PMU events like "cpu-cycles" and "instructions" could be properly handled:

1- amplxe-perf record -o p.perf -T -e cpu-cycles,instructions -- ps

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8410 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
 8458 pts/0    00:00:00 amplxe-perf
 8467 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.024 MB p.perf (96 samples) ]
```

2- amplxe-cl -import p.perf -r r2

```
amplxe: Importing a new result 100 % done                                      
amplxe: Using result path `/home/amad/r2'
amplxe: Executing actions 19 % Resolving information for `libprocps.so.6.0.0'  
amplxe: Warning: Cannot locate debugging information for file `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.6.0.0'.
amplxe: Executing actions 21 % Resolving information for `vmlinux'             
amplxe: Warning: Cannot locate debugging information for the Linux kernel. Source-level analysis will not be possible. Function-level analysis will be limited to kernel symbol tables. See the Enabling Linux Kernel Analysis topic in the product online help for instructions.
amplxe: Executing actions 75 % Generating a report                             
Collection and Platform Info
----------------------------
Parameter         r2                                  
----------------  ------------------------------------
Operating System  4.15.0-13-generic                   
Computer Name     amad-pc                             
Result Size       2766877                             
Collector Type    Driverless Perf per-process sampling

CPU
---
Parameter          r2        
-----------------  ----------
Frequency          3600000000
Logical CPU Count  16        

Summary
-------
Elapsed Time:             0.011
Paused Time:              0.0  
CPU Time:                 0.011
Average CPU Utilization:  0.897

Event summary
-------------
Hardware Event Type  Hardware Event Count:Self  Hardware Event Sample Count:Self  Events Per Sample
-------------------  -------------------------  --------------------------------  -----------------
cpu-cycles                            40521584                                45  4000             
instructions                          36302909                                51  4000             
amplxe: Executing actions 100 % done
```

What is wrong with Intel_pt data?